# Drools 7 - Timer Cron can't stop for loaded rules from DB

Tags: spring-boot, cron, spring-data-jpa, drools, drools-flow

I'm using Drools 7 + Sprint boot + Hibernate JPA. I didn't use the drl file-system for my project. I generate the drool file at runtime using the [java program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62968927/7130858) and save it to my db. There after i will load into my drools as [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746308/7130858). Everything working fine for me. Only thing when i used the cron expression is not updated in my drools session. Let's say initially in my db have one rule with timer cron-expression to trigger every 2 mins. When load the [rules from db](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746308/7130858) in the first time, rules are load in drools session and Cron trigger every 2 mins. Thereafter i have updated cron-expression to trigger every 5 mins in my database and [reload it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62746308/7130858) without stop my application, and rules are loaded. But now trigger was executed every 2 mins and every 5 mins. The previous cron still running.
So i want to remove all active drools stuff like scheduled cron rules before reload. And also how to stop scheduled cron in drools. Did i miss anything in my drools [configuration](https://github.com/jonashackt/spring-boot-starter-drools/blob/master/src/main/java/de/codecentric/drools/configuration/DroolsAutoConfiguration.java).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You really need to put your code into your question, not link to it in half a dozen other locations.

Comment: Also you need to delete the old cron trigger. You don't 'update' triggers, you add new ones and delete the existing one. You just omitted the 'delete'.